# AWS S3 delete all the objects or within in a given date range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am really having a hard time of deleting my bucket `jananath-logs-bucket-new`. It has over 70 TB of data and I need to delete the entire bucket. This has files from `2019`

I tried deleting the bucket and since it has many small files (over 50 millions), it take so much time and the UI (browser hangs). So I thought, let the AWS do it for me.

So I tried the lifecycle rules. So I created the two rules

1. delete-all-from-start
2. delete-all-from-start-2

And below are the screenshots of each rule:

`delete-all-from-start`

[image]

`delete-all-from-start-2`

[image]

And both the rules look like this now:
[image]

But my objects are not deleted.

I have given the **number of days** for each field as `1` thinking it would delete everything from 2019 (where the first object is created).

Can someone help me on this?

1. How can I delete the **entire** objects from the bucket from the `2019`
2. Is it possible to delete the objects between a date range - say from `2020-2021` ?

Thank you,
Have a great day!

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/empty-bucket.html) a lifecycle policy is a valid way to empty a bucket. Please note that there may be a delay for [expiring objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html):

> When an object reaches the end of its lifetime based on its lifecycle
> policy, Amazon S3 queues it for removal and removes it asynchronously.
> There might be a delay between the expiration date and the date at
> which Amazon S3 removes an object.

Comment: Yes but I have setup these rules about 4 weeks ago.

Comment: The delete-all-from-start rule looks good and should mark as expired all objects that are older than one day. The expired objects will need another day to be permanently deleted. Your second rule delete-all-from-start-2 does nothing. Do you still see objects older than 2 days?

Comment: I followed this video by AWS to create the two rules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPRMYFCTvPw&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices

Comment: Yes, this rule is needed, if you have versioning enabled in your bucket.

Comment: I need to know `Do the two rules apply to all the objects even older than some years? Or the rule applied only for the newly created objects after the rule is created?`

Comment: The rule applies to all bucket objects, even if they are created before the rules were set. The rules look good to me and your objects should have been deleted.